# What is the best way to implement oauth2 to a react native app using expo's managed workflow?

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, expo

I have looked all over the internet and there doesn't seem to be any clear way to implement oauth2 to my react native app. Both the Facebook and Google sign in methods found in the expo documentation have been deprecated and these are the 2 main ones I want to use. On top of that, the expo documentation is not very clear on the best way to do this. Does anyone know of an easy and stable way to implement oath2 in a react native app using expo's managed workflow?

Answer (score 1):

To implement google sign-in you can use following package, please follow the instructions carefully under expo section.
[react-native-google-signin-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-google-signin/google-signin)

And to implement facebook sign-in you can use the following package, again please follow the instructions carefully under expo section.
[react-native-fbsdk-next](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next/#expo-installation)

Or you can use firebase and firebase authentication to implement social signin features from multiple social media platforms.

[firebase authentication expo](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/#user-authentication)